# Send direct link to invite B2B User in Azure AD Enterprise App

Tags: azure-active-directory

How do I send a direct link to my Azure AD Enterprise Application to an External guest user?

For example, a brand new gmail account that doesn't have a microsoft account, I don't want to invite them via email. I want to just send an email with a link to my app, they do not have a microsoft account setup.

This describes exactly what I want:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/redemption-experience#redemption-through-a-direct-link

But it doesn't say how to actually do it. This is from the link above:

> A guest inviter can invite a guest user by sending out a direct link
>   to a shared app. For the guest user, the redemption experience is as
>   easy as signing in to the app that was shared with them. They can
>   click a link to the app, review and accept the privacy terms, and then
>   seamlessly access the app. In most cases, guest users no longer need
>   to click a redemption URL in an invitation email.

Comment: You're right . I think it should be a documentation issue. There aren't any steps about how to approach it. I have give a feedback to this documentation and also involve this documenation owner to fix this. I will updated if it has any process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this is done through the Graph API, which isn't mentioned in that documentation.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/invitation_post

HTTP request
POST /invitations

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/invitations
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 551

{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "yyy@test.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://myapp.com"
}
```

`sendInvitationMessage` boolean is false by default. Which means an invitation is not sent to the user. However, the user will still need to "redeem" the invitation (create a Microsoft account, like setup their password).

When you POST to /invitations you can actually post the entire invitation object, which also isn't clear in these docs.

```
{
  "invitedUserDisplayName": "string",
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "string",
  "invitedUserMessageInfo": {"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.invitedUserMessageInfo"},
  "sendInvitationMessage": false,
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "string",
  "inviteRedeemUrl": "string",
  "status": "string",
  "invitedUser": [{"@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.user"}]
}
```

Comment: but in that Graph call you are already `adding the guest to your directory first`! Your original question was how to send a link to the app without adding him first (or was not explicitly declared that you added the guest already?). If you just use the portal UI it will send the link automatically (to myapps.microsoft.com, and the app will be there). And you can do this in [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/new-azureadmsinvitation?view=azureadps-2.0) You do not need Graph, unless you really want to. And documentation said you can use PowerShell, no?

Comment: The point is - if you know the link, you do not need to do neither PowerShell nor Graph. Just add the user as guest from the UI and send him the link over e-mail. Period. In both cases - your Graph discovery and PowerShell you already know the link for the app. Imagine you want to add a guest who does not have real e-mail address (user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com - without e-mail address). There are a lot of production workloads (using custom domains) with no real e-mail behind the UPN. And this improvement addresses all these users. Because there is no e-mail behind the UPN, you can send the link.

Comment: We moved to AWS and haven't looked back.